# Bootstrap Datepicker unable to change endDates

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I got radio button where the name is "**Type**" and the value is "**Standard**" and "**Trial**". Then i also have a text-box where the id is "**datepicker**".
So, when i click the standard button, the endDate for datepicker suppose to be **3 days** and when i click trial button, the endDate for datepicker suppose to be **1 days**.

My problem now is when i checked radio button with "**Standard**" value, then the endDate become *3 days*. But when i checked radio button with "**Trial**" value, the endDate still *3 days*. Otherwise when i checked "**Trial**" first then, the value will become *1 days* and when checked "**Standard**" the result of endDate will be same that is *1 days*.

i have tried the `$(".datepicker").datepicker("refresh");` and `$(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy");` but it's seems not working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/datepicker.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.datepicker').val('dd/mm/yyyy');
            dateExpiry();
        });
        $("input[name='Type']").change(function () {
            $('.datepicker').val('dd/mm/yyyy');
            dateExpiry();
        });

        function dateExpiry() {
            var type = $("input[name='Type']:checked").val();
            if (type == 'Trial') {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    startDate: '-0d',
                    endDate: '+1d',
                    autoclose: true
                });
            }
            else if (type == 'Standard') {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                    startDate: '-0d',
                    endDate: '+3d',
                    autoclose: true
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not create datepicker a new. Use [`setEndDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate) method to set end date value.

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startDate: '-0d',
  endDate: '+1d',
  autoclose: true
});
ChangeRange();
$("input[name='Type']").change(ChangeRange);
function ChangeRange() {
  if ($("input[name='Type']:checked").val()=="Standard") {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', '+3d');
  }
  else if ($("input[name='Type']:checked").val()=="Trial") {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('setEndDate', '+1d');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Standard">
    Standard
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="Type" value="Trial" checked="checked">
    Trial
  </label>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="21/06/2017">
  <div class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```